# How to set user agent using a proxy?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer.connect to connect to a remote browser service (browserless.io), and page.authenticate to authenticate on a remote proxy. But everytime I try to set User Agent, it fails.

```
   async function taskProcessor(task) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: wss://chrome.browserless.io/?token=b&stealth&headless=false&slowMo=1000&ignoreDefaultArgs=--hide-scrollbars,--disable-default-apps&--proxy-server=https://br-pr.oxylabs.io:20000`})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate({
      username: 'user',
      password: 'password'
    })

  const userAgent = new UserAgent();

  console.log(userAgent.toString());
  
  await page.setViewport({width:1920,height:1080});

  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());

  await page.goto('https://google.com',{waitUntil:"networkidle2"});

  const userAgentString = await page.evaluate(() => navigator.userAgent);
  console.log(userAgentString);
```

Output:

```
2023-07-25T23:38:31.139741+00:00 app[web.1]: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
2023-07-25T23:38:45.331961+00:00 app[web.1]: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Is there some way to set user agent using puppeteer.connect and proxy? Everything works if I remove the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--user-agent` to your `browserWSEndpoint` parameter of `puppeteer.connect` as documented [here](https://www.browserless.io/docs/setting-a-user-agent#hosted-service).